# Humankind colonizes planets, main character is a "spartan" with augmented bones

Tags: story-identification

I read a book series 12 or so years ago, and I need help getting the title. It's set in the future. Mankind has branched out to the stars and many planets were colonized. Humans started to evolve differently on these planets. Now, I remember the main character as being a "spartan", and he grew up and was trained on an arid planet. His entire people were massacred and he was the only survivor. An advanced alien race took him in and augmented his bones to be unbreakable. I think that these aliens looked like owls, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 10):

This is the Last Legionary series by Douglas Hill.  The protagonist is Keill Randor a member of the Legion of Moros, a planetary culture whose primary export is mercenary skill and is recognized through the galaxy as the source of the best fighting forces.

Warning, light spoilers.

Keill is a champion among the Legion.  He is off-planet when Moros is attacked and decimated by a force under control of an entity only known as the "Overlord".   Keill received a lighter dose of the same process which killed the Legion, but condemning him to a slow death as his bones decay.

Under care of an alien presence opposed to the Warlord, Keill's skeleton is completely replaced with an infrangible substance (a la Wolverine's admantium) at once curing him and increasing his fighting effectiveness.

Keill's new mission is to help find and stop the Overlord.  He is acommpanied on his journey by a telepathic alien companion named Glr

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keill_Randor

Comment: Yep, @beichst is right on the money. I had an omnibus edition in paperback of this book years ago, though it didnt have the prequel included in it (lost it though and couldnt remember the name of the series until I saw this post)

Comment: That would be the one. Thanks

Comment: Please click the check-mark beside the answer, @Aaron, to signify it was what you were looking for.