# Scifi book from the 80's. The last of a warrior race

Tags: story-identification

**The hero was the last of his kind (not a human) who was a member of a warrior race.**

- He had a sidekick alien that communicated through telepathy.
- I think he was described as a "centurion" (?) or something similar.
- It would have been published approx 1978 to 1990.
- I think it was at least a couple of books.

Comment: Previous asked about http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51763/need-help-identifying-this-space-novel http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8499/identify-book-about-fighting-tournament-with-the-opponent-wearing http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47022/series-of-young-adult-science-fiction-books-from-early-1980s-about-last-of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30561/trying-to-recall-a-ya-scifi-series-from-the-80s-or-70s and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30672/humankind-colonizes-planets-main-character-is-a-spartan-with-augmented Very popular "lost" title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Last Legionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Hill#Last_Legionary) series by Douglas hill

The protagonist is the last of a warrior race, all the others were killed by a radiation weapon and he has a small flying telepathic alien as his companion. 
The first 4 books below are the overall story arc where he is the last of his people and meets the telepathic alien, the 5th book is a prequel.

> 1. [Galactic Warlord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_Warlord) (1979)
> 2. Deathwing over Veynaa (1980)
> 3. Day of the Starwind (1980)
> 4. Planet of the Warlord (1981)
> 5. Young Legionary (1982)